Asymptotics in an optimal stopping problem
Let us consider a card deck with $2n$ cards: $n$ red and $n$ black. You draw cards one by one without replacement. For each red card you draw you get $+1$ point while for each black card you draw you get $-1$ point. You stop drawing cards whenever you want.
The strategy that maximizes the expected score can be found easily numerically using the associated Bellman equation. With a $32$ card deck I find an expected score of $2.05$.
Is there any way to find the asymptotics of the expected optimal score when $n$ goes to $+\infty$?
I bet this involves a Brownian bridge but I do not manage to get a result.
